# Secure IIS website from unauthorized writes

Tags: iis, windows-server

I am setting up windows EC2 server. I have created a website in that server using IIS. After creation IIS, assign them pool by default whose identity is `ApplicationPoolIdentity`. Website works fine.

However, I have set up a file upload script in one of those site and without setting of any extra permission that script is able to upload file in any folder. I consider kind of these things dangerous. When I was working on shared hosting I needed to specify which folder I need to set write permission otherwise I cannot upload.

How can I prevent write access to other folder than I choose?

Comment: This should help http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/planning-for-security/secure-content-in-iis-through-file-system-acls